# How do you get template preprocess functions to fire on hook theme suggestions?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

If you have a theme function like [theme_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) for instance. I know you can do something like this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$varialbes) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

and that will print out the all the variables (if you have [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) enabled). Then I see theme_hook_suggestions like this "field__field_date__featured_event". However, when I try to do this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field__field_date__featured_event(&$varialbes) {
  dpm($variables);
}
```

The above does not work at all. Why is this? Is it possible to use a preprocess function on a theme suggestion? or are theme suggestions just for theme overrides and not for preprocessing?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this before you can do that...

```
/*
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
    if ($vars['SOME_FIELD']) {
        $function = 'YOURTHEME_preprocess_field__'.$vars['SOME_FIELD'];
        if (function_exists($function)) {
            $function($vars);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so there isn't a way to use the theme suggestions to automatically preprocess things? Then what's the point of them? thanks!

Comment: Think your getting confused with the conventions for templates. theme_hook_suggestions are suggestions templates, not hooks.

Comment: @DavidBarratt Alex is right, they're for template files, not for preprocess functions. `theme_hook_suggestions` are _added_ in a preprocess function, so for them to also affect other preprocess functions could easily introduce a nasty in-escapable loop

Comment: It's actually a bug http://drupal.org/node/939462

Comment: @barraponto Thanks I haven't come across that one before, I just assumed it was like that by design